# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Python container application directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a Python Flask app.  It defaults to installing my application in /opt/python/current/app.  How do I change it to be in /opt/python/current/myappname?

Comment: I spent some good time trying to figure out how to alter the application's directory assigned by AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I want to take you along this journey so you can understand how difficult Amazon made it to alter the something that appears so trivial. I'll post it when I get the chance.

Comment: check this out in the meantime: http://www.jmccc.com/blog/archives/2015/06/17/amazon-elastic-beanstalk-hooks/